# Deny permissions for master in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, security

I created a new database on a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance and a login/user for it. I have set the user to `db_owner` so he can't view any other databases on that server but he can see and query the `master`

database. Is there a way to hide/deny permissions for the `master` database? Are there any possible vulnerabilities if I leave him to query the `master` database or is there a way to deny him access to the `master` database?

Comment: What are you trying to hide from them specifically? Sometimes some access to master is important, e.g. if the user will need to execute certain stored procedures, or query from utility tables that are proliferated in code all over the web (e.g. `master.dbo.spt_values`).

Comment: There will be no need for that. All stored procedures (if any) will be custom regarding that database only. I tried to query the master in some ways and for now I didn't find any information about the other databases that are hidden from that user

Comment: @AArmin The views and tables in master have `select` permission granted to `public`. When a user is not explicitly granted or denied permissions, then the effective permission is inherited from `public`. I agree with Aaron's point - what exactly you want to hide from the users ? You can explicitly deny permissions to users using dynamic SQL.